# Spring, abstract class and annotations

Tags: java, spring

I've got a pretty simple abstract class

```
public abstract class AbstractServiceActions {

    @Autowired
    protected DatabaseModel dbModel;

    protected User user;
    protected boolean complete;
    protected String serviceResult;

    public AbstractServiceActions(User user) {
        this.user = user;
        this.serviceResult = "";
    }

    public abstract String doAction();
    }
```

Now you can see, I'm trying to autowire the DatabaseModel. But in my extended class I only recieve null for the dbModel.

```
@Component
public class CreateDatabaseAction extends AbstractServiceActions {
....
}
```

Question: Am I trying something impossible here?

Comment: Are you having spring component-scan the package that your abstract class is in?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your setup seems fine. The reason perhaps lies elsewhere. Maybe  you are instantiating the class with `new CreateDatabaseAction()`, rather than letting spring do this.

Comment: +1: Spring allows autowiring in abstract classes, so your suggestion makes good sense!

Comment: @Bozho but how do you let Spring create instance here, constructor of base class expects a parameter, how do you set that in the Annotation?

Comment: there are many ways to do that. annotations, xml, javaconfig.

Answer (score 1):

Use `@Autowired` and not `@Inject` from `javax.inject`.

Dependency injection in abstract class only works for spring's `@Autowired`.

FYI, I'm using Spring 4.0; Java 6