# Send message to different Kafka topics based on configuration

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I would like to send data to different Kafka messages based on configuration:

```
ResponseFactory processingPeply = null;

        switch(endpointType)
        {
            case "email":
                ProducerRecord<String, Object> record = new ProducerRecord<>("tp-email.request", tf);
                RequestReplyFuture<String, Object, Object> replyFuture = processingTransactionEmailReplyKafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(record);
                SendResult<String, Object> sendResult = replyFuture.getSendFuture().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                ConsumerRecord<String, Object> consumerRecord = replyFuture.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

                processingPeply = (ResponseFactory) consumerRecord.value();
              break;
            case "sms":
                ProducerRecord<String, Object> record = new ProducerRecord<>("tp-sms.request", tf);
                RequestReplyFuture<String, Object, Object> replyFuture = processingTransactionSmsReplyKafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(record);
                SendResult<String, Object> sendResult = replyFuture.getSendFuture().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                ConsumerRecord<String, Object> consumerRecord = replyFuture.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

                processingPeply = (ResponseFactory) consumerRecord.value();
              break;
            case "network":
                ProducerRecord<String, Object> record = new ProducerRecord<>("tp-network.request", tf);
                RequestReplyFuture<String, Object, Object> replyFuture = processingTransactionNetworkReplyKafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(record);
                SendResult<String, Object> sendResult = replyFuture.getSendFuture().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                ConsumerRecord<String, Object> consumerRecord = replyFuture.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

                processingPeply = (ResponseFactory) consumerRecord.value();
              break;
              
            default:
                processingPeply = ResponseFactory.builder().status("error").build();
        }
```

I currently get:

- Variable 'record' is already defined in the scope
- Variable 'sendResult' is already defined in the scope
- Variable 'consumerRecord' is already defined in the scope

Do you know how I can redesign the code in some better way so I can solve the issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suggesting here 4 possible approaches, in order to avoid some switch blocks in core code and honor one of [**DRY**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)'s principles, which is avoid duplicated code. *(DRY represents a much bigger concept than just not repeating code).*

---

***1- GeneralHandler and endpoint type childs***

Something like a hierarchical class' tree here, with the different endpoints being an extension of an abstract/general father.

```
                      [GeneralKafkaHandler] - core/common logic
               _______________ | ________________
              |                |                |
              v                v                v
         {SmsHandler}    {EmailHandler}   {NetworkHandler}  -- specific params/methods
```

For example, `getTopic()` and `getFuture()` could be *`abstract`* on the father, and implemented by each child with its own logic. Another option would be making `getKafkaTemplate()` another abstract method (*choose between `getFuture()` or `getKafkaTemplate()`)*. This is a simplification of the hierarchy, and the topic is retrieved from the constructor.

**`Abstract father`**

```
abstract class GeneralKafkaHandler 
{
   public abstract RequestReplyFuture<String, Object, Object> 
                   getFuture(ProducerRecord<>r);
   public abstract String getName();

   protected String topic;
   protected int id;
   ResponseFactory processingPeply = null;

   public GeneralKafkaHandler(String topic, int id) 
   {
       this.topic = topic; 
       this.id = id;
   }

   public void handle(Object tf) //the main/common logic is implemented here
   {
       ProducerRecord<String, Object> record = new ProducerRecord<>(topic, tf);
       RequestReplyFuture<String, Object, Object> rf = getFuture(record);  
       SendResult<String, Object> sr = rf.getSendFuture().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       ConsumerRecord<String, Object> consumerRecord = rf.get(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       processingPeply = (ResponseFactory) consumerRecord.value();
   }

   //...
}
```

**`SmsHandler`**

```
class SmsKafkaHandler extends GeneralKafkaHandler 
{
   //Sms specific variables, methods,..
    
   public SmsKafkaHandler(String topic, int id) 
   {
      super(topic, id);
      //sms code
   }

   @Override
   public String getName() 
   {
      return "SMSHandler_"+topic+"_"+id);
   }

   @Override
   public RequestReplyFuture<String, Object, Object> getFuture(ProducerRecord<> r)
   {
      //sms code
      return processingTransactionSmsReplyKafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(r);
   }

   //...
}
```

**`Main`** (*just an example*)

```
Map<String, GeneralKafkaHandler> handlerMap = new HashMap<>();
handlerMap.put("sms", new SmsKafkaHandler("tp-sms.request",1));
handlerMap.put("smsplus", new SmsKafkaHandler("tp-sms-plus.request",2));
handlerMap.put("email", new EmailKafkaHandler("tp-email.request",1));
//...

handlerMap.get(endpointType.toLowerCase()).handle(tf);
```

There are different options here; For example, sendAndReceive is also a common method for all types, so the `getFuture()` could be altered by just a `getTemplate()` method. There are so many options to play with here.

*This approach would be a good idea if you need/wish to manage each endpoint more in dept; you could consider it if you think the different management is worth, or will be worth in the future; As the core mechanism is the same, different extensions would allow you to fastly implement different endpoint types.*

---

***2- Custom entity***

In essence, there are just 2 different elements regarding the endpoint type:

1. `Topic`
2. `ReplyingKafkaTemplate`

You could wrap them into a single Object. For example:

```
public class TopicEntity
{
  public final String topic;
  public final ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String,Object,Object> template;

  public TopicEntity(String topic, ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String,Object,Object> template)
  {
     this.topic = topic;
     this.template = template;
  }    
}
```

So then you can get this without modifying your current code (*here I assume your templates are already initialized*):

```
TopicEntity smsE = new TopicEntity("tp-sms.request",
                                   processingTransactionSmsReplyKafkaTemplate);
TopicEntity mailE = new TopicEntity("tp-email.request",
                                   processingTransactionEmailReplyKafkaTemplate);

Map<String, TopicEntity> handlerMap = new HashMap<>();
handlerMap.put("sms", smsE);
handlerMap.put("email",mailE);
//...

TopicEntity te = handlerMap.get(endpointType.toLowerCase()); 
//Based on endpoint
ProducerRecord<String, Object> record = new ProducerRecord<>(te.topic, tf);
RequestReplyFuture<String, Object, Object> rf = te.template.sendAndReceive(record);
//Common regardless of endpoint
SendResult<String, Object> sr = rf.getSendFuture().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
ConsumerRecord<String, Object> consumerRecord = rf.get(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
processingPeply = (ResponseFactory) consumerRecord.value();
```

*Pretty simple and also avoids duplicate code; The entity would also allow you to define specific characteristics for each endpoint.*

---

***3- Getter methods***

The simpler way, just to make the main code look cleaner.

```
ProducerRecord<String, Object> record = new ProducerRecord<>(getTopic(endpointType),tf);
RequestReplyFuture<String, Object, Object> replyFuture = getFuture(endpointType,record);
/*rest of the code here (common regardless type)*/
```

And the getters:

```
String getTopic(String e)
{
   switch(e.toLowerCase())
   {
      case "email"  : return "tp-email.request"; 
      case "sms"    : return "tp-sms.request";
      case "network": return "tp-network.request";
      default : /*handle error*/ return null; 
                /*kafka's response - "topic cannot be null");*/
    }
}

RequestReplyFuture<String, Object, Object> getFuture(String e, ProducerRecord<> r)
{
  switch(e.toLowerCase())
  {
     case "email": 
          return processingTransactionEmailReplyKafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(r);
     case "sms" :
           return processingTransactionSmsReplyKafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(r);
     case "network": 
           return processingTransactionNetworkReplyKafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(r);
     default : /*handle error*/ return null;
  }            /*this one should never be executed*/
}
```

---

***4- Single setter***

Well, maybe this one is the simpler way...it would be a fight between approach 3 and 4.

```
ReplyingKafkaTemplate template;
String topic;
//...

void setParameters(String e)
{
  switch(e.toLowerCase())
  {
    case "email"  : 
          topic = "tp-email.request"; 
          template = processingTransactionEmailReplyKafkaTemplate;
          break;         
    case "sms"    :       
          topic = "tp-sms.request"; 
          template = processingTransactionSmsReplyKafkaTemplate;
          break;         
     //...
   }
}
//...

setParameters(endpointType);

ProducerRecord<String, Object> r= new ProducerRecord<>(topic,tf);
RequestReplyFuture<String, Object, Object> replyFuture = template.sendAndReceive(r);
SendResult<String, Object> sr = rf.getSendFuture().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
ConsumerRecord<String, Object> consumerRecord = rf.get(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
processingPeply = (ResponseFactory) consumerRecord.value();
```

---

***1.a)- Spring and GeneralHandler***

*Spoiler: I don't know sh#! about Spring, so this may be totally incorrect.*

From what I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965829/spring-can-you-autowire-inside-an-abstract-class), the abstract class doesn't need any annotation, just the fields that may be accessed by the childs should need `@Autowired`.

```
abstract class GeneralKafkaHandler 
{
   public abstract RequestReplyFuture<String, Object, Object> 
                   getFuture(ProducerRecord<>r);
   public abstract String getName();

   @Autowired
   protected String topic;
   @Autowired
   protected int id;

   ResponseFactory processingPeply = null;

   public GeneralKafkaHandler(String topic, int id) 
   {
       this.topic = topic; 
       this.id = id;
   }

   public void handle(Object tf) //the main/common logic is implemented here
   {
       ProducerRecord<String, Object> record = new ProducerRecord<>(topic, tf);
       RequestReplyFuture<String, Object, Object> rf = getFuture(record);  
       SendResult<String, Object> sr = rf.getSendFuture().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       ConsumerRecord<String, Object> consumerRecord = rf.get(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       processingPeply = (ResponseFactory) consumerRecord.value();
   }

   //...
}
```

And the children should have the `@Component` annotation, as well as `@Autowired` in the constructor; *I'm not really sure about the last one, as the examples I've seen also include fields that are also defined in the child.*

```
@Component
class SmsKafkaHandler extends GeneralKafkaHandler 
{
   //Sms specific variables, methods,..
    
   @Autowired  //not sure about this..
   public SmsKafkaHandler(String topic, int id) 
   {
      super(topic, id);
      //sms code
   }

   @Override
   public String getName() 
   {
      return "SMSHandler_"+topic+"_"+id);
   }

   @Override
   public RequestReplyFuture<String, Object, Object> getFuture(ProducerRecord<> r)
   {
      //sms code
      return processingTransactionSmsReplyKafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(r);
   }

   //...
}
```

*Really, I don't know what I'm talking about regarding this Spring solution, I don't even know what those annotations are, the meme of the dog looking at a computer represents me at this moment. So take this carefully...*

---

***[DRY is for losers](https://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread/39358.html#203288)***

Comment: Excellent answer! One more question. In my case I use Spring Boot. Is it possible to use Spring Service as additional solution?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Thanks Peter! I've tried my best regarding Spring Service, since I never worked with it. I've seen some examples and the updated code may work, even if I can't guarantee it...I didn't really know what a Spring Service was... :_ ) - Updated the answer with an appendix for a Spring based approach

Comment: *correction: I still don't know what a Spring Service is*

Comment: Here is more description: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_service_components.htm

Comment: What an extraordinary answer @aran, ¡maravilloso!

Comment: Brilliant answer! The link `DRY is for losers` seems to be dead. If the page does not exist anymore, you may simply link to the [DRY on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) or some other equivalent page intended for the purpose.