# How to annotate an instance variable derived from an abstract Class?

Tags: java, inheritance, annotations

I have the following abstract Java class:

```
abstract class AbstractDto {

  String id;

  public void setId(String id) { this.id = id; }    

  public String getId() {return id; }

}
```

I also have class which extends the abstract class:

```
class SomeDto extends AbstractDto {

  @SomeAnnotation
  String id;

}
```

I want to annotate an instance variable derived from an abstract class. I am not sure if this is the way to go as I did it. I know that Java does not provide variable overloading so this is shadowing.

So what happens if I do:

```
public void go(AbstractDto dto) {
  println("dto.id: "+dto.id);
}

AbstractDto dto = new SomeDto();
dto.setId("1234");
go(dto);
```

Since I do shadowing when I set the id of SomeDto then there is an `id`variable inherited from AbstractDto which is still not set.

**How can I annotate an instance variable defined in an abstract super class?**

Edit: When I do:

```
SomeDto dto = new SomeDto();
dto.setId("123");
```

Which id was set the one in AbstractDto or the one in SomeDto?
What happens I a method in the Abstract class reads from id which id is then used?

Comment: It's called [`shadowing`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1).  This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16941179/variable-shadowing-in-java

Comment: The only derivation here is of the class itself. The `id` variable in the derived class is not derived, inherited, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you provided is called *shadowing*, there is no overriding for fields in Java.

More about *shadowing* could be found in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing):

> In computer programming, variable shadowing occurs when a variable
>   declared within a certain scope (decision block, method, or inner
>   class) has the same name as a variable declared in an outer scope.

So, to use your annotation, you can either annotate your `id` variable in the abstract class (all inherited classes could use that annotated variable), or just annotate the `id` variable of `SomeDto` but you have to be aware that it's a new variable (no relation with the id's super class variable)

**Regarding your second question:**

> Which id was set the one in AbstractDto or the one in SomeDto?

The id of SomeDto will be set because the reference variable type of `dto`  is `SomeDto`. To explain more, in the inherited class `SomeDto` you defined another `id` variable which hides the first one, so each call using a reference to that class or any inherited class of `SomeDto` will call the new `id` variable defined in the `SomeDto` class.

> What happens I a method in the Abstract class reads from id which id
>   is then used?

Each call to `id` in the abstract class will use the `id` in the abstract class, so a method implemented in `AbstractDto` and using the variable `id` will use the `AbstractDto` one.

**Annotating instance variables defined in abstract super class:**

This is some real life examples where instance variables of abstract classes are annotated:

- [Spring, abstract class and annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921899/spring-abstract-class-and-annotations)
- [Spring and Abstract class - injecting properties in abstract classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184556/spring-and-abstract-class-injecting-properties-in-abstract-classes)

Comment: Please see my edit: Which id was set the one in AbstractDto or the one in SomeDto?

Comment: What happens I a method in the Abstract class reads from id which id is then used?

Comment: @confile is that answer your question or you have other questions? please feel free to ask

Comment: How can I annotate an instance variable defined in an abstract super class? Such that the Abstract class can still use the variable.

Comment: @confile just annotate it like any instance variable, no matter if tha class is abstract or not, you can find examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921899/spring-abstract-class-and-annotations) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184556/spring-and-abstract-class-injecting-properties-in-abstract-classes)