# java.lang.InstantiationException with abstract class Using Conponent-Scan

Tags: java, spring

I have an application that is based on webservices in which multiple classes are present. Some classes types are `abstract` that is extended in other classes for defining the body to the abstract class methods. I used spring for instantiate the classes in spring context xml. I have used `context:component-scan base-package="com.test.webservices"` it scan all the `@Component` class and instantiated but it will not scan the abstract class.

Now My question here is that is there any solution for scanning abstract class using component-scan ?

Code is like-

```
@Component
public abstract class HibernateEntityManager{ ... }

@Component
public class HibernateGenericDaoImpl extends HibernateEntityManager{ ... }
```

In applicationContext.xml I have

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.webservices"/>
```

that scan all classes excepts abstract classes.

Exception is :-

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/ApplicationContext/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.test.webservices.utils.HibernateEntityManager]: Is it an abstract class?; nested exception is java.lang.InstantiationException
```

Comment: Create beans only for concrete subclass. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921899/spring-abstract-class-and-annotations

Answer (score 3):

Your abstract class can't be a bean specifically because you can't instantiate it. Remove the annotation from the abstract class and have it only on the concrete class.

Comment: Thanks! In that case how do i use child class parent="" field in xml config for parent abstract class? This condition forces me that my every super class has to be concrete class if i have to use parent="" field in xml config.

Answer (score 0):

The use of @Component annotation when used in combination with

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.inn.webservices"/>
```

Spring tries to create singleton beans for the annotated classes. In your case you should have annotated abstract class. Put your @Component annoation on implementation classes instead.